# What is the difference between wallet versions 159900 and 169900

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat

The wallet from 2018 version,159900 to the one i have now which is version 169900,what is the difference in the two diff versions?

Answer (score 1):

169900 is a version that implements a certain feature required for upgrading older wallets to support split HD chains (introduced in version 139900). It exists because the upgrade mechanism required a new version for this necessary feature to be implemented.

The feature added is a pre-HD split keypool. This allows users who upgrade from prior to HD chain split to still use their pre-split keypool. The version number had to be incremented in order to allow the upgrade to work - it is not possible to upgrade a pre-HD split wallet to 139900, the upgrade must be to 169900.

New wallets use 169900 as their version number because it happens to be highest version number.

Comment: Thanks andrew,but it still saying i have one version 15990 on chainquery and version 169900 main on the core, is the chainquery one just a mock and untrue then,

Comment: 159900 just means the wallet as made on an older version. Wallets are not upgraded automatically so the version number will not change until you explicitly upgrade it.

Comment: @AndrewChow I think OP is trying to say they're comparing with the output of running the same command on chainquery.com. Marc: it is almost certainly simulated, but we don't have any insight in how that site works.

Comment: ThanSk Andrew i thought chainquery was simulated, so the only true info is what comes from the core..only got 8000 blocks to go then i can get to work.,

Answer (score 0):

The difference between version 159900 and 169900 is a minor feature, allowing the upgrade from pre-HD wallets or not. It is unlikely to matter for an end user.

Both versions imply the wallet was last created or upgraded using a Bitcoin Core version from 2018 or later.